Additional hardware requirements for dual-profile use (personal & work) on low-end Android Smartphones
I have made the observation, respectively some colleagues of mine, that some low-end phones struggle after being enrolled into our mobile device management (MDM). We use Microsoft Intune for that, but for this question, this shouldn't be relevant.
Before rolling out the MDM, the low-end phones were used as they were, and some additional apps were installed for work purposes. Nothing too tasking.
When we introduced MDM, all existing phones were automatically enrolled as personally owned, work profile. Hence, a work profile was created on them.
Colleagues then remarked that certain low-end phones, specific models or makers aren't relevant here, have suffered severly performancewise.
On the other hand, newly enrolled phones of the same model under the fully managed scheme, did not show any noticeable degradation in performance.
Does creating separate profiles, one personal and one for work, in the enrollment into an MDM translate into an increase of the minimum requirements for RAM, the CPU etc.?
Naively, or intuitively, this seems logical, since having two profiles and a set of duplicated apps running at the same time should result in more base-use of system resources. However, I couldn't find any information on this, as in "You must be this tall, to support a personal and a work profile".
Is my hunch correct? Low-end phones being fine for single-profile use, but not for having two profiles.

What is your definition of a low-end Android Smartphone (especially RAM)? On thE Google page the requirement 2GB RAM is mentioned, but based on the Android versions this requirements was not updated for many years: https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/9563584

This may be of some relevance //I don't have any exposure to MDMs

I wonder if they create a Work Profile using Island, Parallel Space, or similar apps, would they suffer the same performance issue..? Or does the MDM add another load, due to Android Device Policy?

So, the specific phone is spec'ed with 3 GB RAM upwards. The CPU is a mix of A75 and A55 Cortex cores well below 2 GHz.
